# Fitting a nls with ggplot2 - error object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting, data-fitting, nls

I am trying to do a nls fit with ggplot with the following data:
    `df <- data.frame(t = 0:30, m = c(125.000000, 100.248858,  70.000000,  83.470795, 100.000000,  65.907870,  66.533715,  53.588087, 61.332351,  43.927435,  40.295448,  44.713459,  32.533143,  36.640336,  40.154711,  23.080295, 39.867928,  22.849786,  35.014645,  17.977267,  21.159180,  27.998273,  21.885735,  14.273962, 13.665969,  11.816435,  25.189016,   8.195644,  17.191337,  24.283354,  17.722776)`

The code I have so far (a bit simplified) is

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = t, y = m)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method = "nls", formula=log(y)~x)
```

But I get the following error

```
Error in cll[[1L]] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

I have browsed stackoverflow and found similar issues, but I have not been able to solve the problem. I would really like to plot the data without transforming the axis.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `nls` you have to specify the parameters more carefully. Also, you probably don't want to use `log(y)`, because that will plot the logarithm instead of `y`. My guess is that you want to use something like `y  ~ exp(a + b * x)`. See below for an example.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = t, y = m))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "nls", formula = y  ~ exp(a + b * x), start=list(a=0, b=1), se=FALSE)
```

You could also use `glm` instead of `nls`. For instance the following gives you the same solution.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = t, y = m))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", formula = y  ~ x, family=gaussian(link = "log"), se=FALSE)
```